# Ошибка Unchecked

Tags: javascript, php

В Console выдает такую ошибку - Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
Вроде все работает. Чтобы она могла значить?

Answer (score 0):

проблема в расширениях браузера, попробуйте отключить все по очереди, это поможет выявить проблемное и отключить

Comment: Открыл в другом браузере, ошибка не пропала.

Comment: так я же и сказал что это из-за расширения браузера

Comment: А расширение браузера, это доп проги к примеру в хроме, я так понял что изза одной из них эта ошибка. В Опере этих расширений нет, открыт страничку в опере ошибка должна уйти, не ушла.